# Edit Links in public directory

Tags: directory, redirect

I have a profile setup as a directory in WordPress (5.1.1 w/CiviCRM 5.11.0). I set the profile to show the edit link to those who have permission to edit. I have an ACL setup for editors to edit specific contacts. A couple things are happening.

- The edit link shows on all contacts, even those who the logged in
  user does not have permission to edit according to the ACL.
- If you click an edit link that the user does not have permission to
  edit they get redirected to the site home page.
- Edits work fine for contacts the user has permission to edit.

Seeing the Edit link is not a big deal for this application. The redirection when they do not have permission is going to cause confusion.

I have tried this on two separate sites with the same results.

Comment: Just adding the Help test for that field. "Edit Link. Check this box if you want to include a link in the listings to Edit profile fields. Only users with permission to edit the contact will see this link."